# Mathematical operations and Twig variables

Tags: theming

Is it legal to do this in a node template with Drupal 8?

```
{% set percentVariable = content.field_my_customfield.0 * 100 / content.field_my_second_customfield.0 %}
```

which will be output like this

```
<div style="width:{{ percentVariable }}{{'%'}}"></div>
```

Both fields deliver integer values to that variable

Is there any major syntax error or misunderstanding in doing so?

Comment: You really should do this in a preprocess hook and pass this variable along instead of put it in twig.

Comment: I really don't understand, is that supposed to give an error for some reason? Only Math between integers is allowed and not variables?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269622/how-make-addition-from-2-variable-twig this thread seems to confirm it should be possible!

Comment: Again, I would stress to do this from a preprocess hook where you have PHP available to do such operations and not rely on twig. Anyway, this is likely an error for you because you are using the render array variable and not the raw value from the node field object. The question you linked to uses simple variables to do the addition; `content.field_name` vars are not simple variables. Such things are just easier to create as a new variable and pass into the template to be printed out. Easier to debug, easier to reason about.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/overriding-themable-output/setting-up-variables-for-use-in-a-template-preprocess-and is this what you're referring to? Is that still valid for Drupal 8?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is *legal* to do mathematical operations in Twig (and in PHP as well). The issue you have is you are trying to calculate render arrays, which doesn't work, no matter which programming language you use. You need to do this on the field values. For example the first value you are looking for:

in PHP:

```
$value = $node->field_my_customfield->value;
```

or in Twig:

```
{% set value = node.field_my_customfield.value %}
```

This code should work then in Twig:

```
{% set percentVariable = node.field_my_customfield.value * 100 / node.field_my_second_customfield.value %}
<div style="width:{{ percentVariable|round }}%"></div>
```